# Azure Servicebus AMQP URL not accepted / or how to connect Liberty to Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, jms, amqp, websphere-liberty, qpid

I got a problem getting Azure ServiceBus connected via AMQP through QPID to IBM WAS LibertyProfile.
I followed the tutorial at [Microsoft Docs Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp) but I got following exception (the URL is obfuscated):

```
Caused by: Not an AMQP URL amqps://POLICY:ENCODEDKEY@NAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net
at org.apache.qpid.url.URLHelper.parseError(URLHelper.java:143)
at org.apache.qpid.url.URLHelper.parseError(URLHelper.java:138)
at org.apache.qpid.client.url.URLParser.parseURL(URLParser.java:150)
at org.apache.qpid.client.url.URLParser.<init>(URLParser.java:41)
at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionURL.<init>(AMQConnectionURL.java:62)
at org.apache.qpid.client.AMQConnectionFactory.<init>(AMQConnectionFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.qpid.ra.QpidResourceAdapter.createFactory(QpidResourceAdapter.java:747)
at org.apache.qpid.ra.QpidResourceAdapter.createAMQConnectionFactory(QpidResourceAdapter.java:656)
```

In the server.xml I used qpid-ra-6.1.2.rar as resource adapter.

If I use a small example application with the same URL in jndi.properties, the connection works perfect.

The difference between the two solutions is that I use the resource adapter. Am I wrong with using it ?
How would it be better to connect from WAS Liberty via AMQP to Azure Service Bus ?

I'm looking forward to hopefully get some answers or hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I use a JCA adapter which is not able to connect to a AMQP 1.0 broker. In the example application I use qpid amqp 1.0 client jms.
At the moment there is no amqp 1.0 JCA resource adapter.
Also there is no further work on the resource adapter:
[Qpid Jira Ticket 7716](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-7716)

Comment: I asked further questions here: [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18e17c97-cbcf-4bc5-8624-8c10b295b2d8/azure-service-bus-usage-in-javaee-jca-websphere-liberty-profile)